# Liferay Studio Not Sync

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I encountered problem in Liferay developer studio, i notice there is no **synchronized** word inside the **red box** per portlet.

Now all my changes in themes and portlets didnt update im stuck in last state before i get this error

I've done to build it, redeploy and remove and drag&drop in server but the same result

i cant proceed my work with this problem

Is anyone can help me?

> **Working LDS fresh**

[image]

> **Encounter ERROR in my LDS**

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you turned on *Automatically publising* for your server.

There is special view in Eclipse called *Server Log*. It does not contain the server log (as one might guess), as that one is shown in the *Console* view. Instead it contains all messages from the server synchronization and similar things.

If you open that view and select your server you might see the error message that causes the publish process to stop. Usually it is a single file that causes this problem, which either does not exist in your source folder (refresh will help in that case) or is not writable in your target folder - often because of permissions.

Comment: I think i will start new install and load all things project from my old LDS to continue than waiting to fix this, by the way thank you @Tobias